# Determine whether this map is an isomorphism

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Assume all the normed spaces are over $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. Let $c$ be the space of all convergent sequences equipped with the supremum norm. For $g\in\ell^1$, define the map

$$T_g:c\to \mathbb{F},\quad T_g(f)=g(1)\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g(k+1)f(k).$$

It is easy to see that $T_g\in c^*$. Now let

$$\phi:\ell^1\to c^*,\quad \phi(g)=T_g.$$

Show that $\phi$ is an isometry and determine whether $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

First I showed that $\phi$ is an isometry. It is trivial that $\phi$ is linear, and it is bounded since

$$\Vert T_g\Vert\leq\Vert g\Vert_1.$$

On the other hand, since $g\in\ell^1$, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}|g(k)|=0$. So for each $N\in\mathbb{N}$, let

$$f_N(k)=\begin{cases}\text{sgn}(g(k+1)),&k\leq N\\
\text{sgn}(g(1)),&k>N\end{cases}$$

So $f_N\in c$ and $\Vert f_N\Vert_\infty=1$ for all $N$. It follows by triangle inequality that

$$\Vert T_g(f_N)\Vert\geq\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}|g(k)|-\sum_{k=N+2}^\infty|g(k)|$$

Thus $$\Vert T_g\Vert\geq\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}|g(k)|=\Vert g\Vert_1$$

which means $\phi$ is an isometry.

To determine whether $\phi$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to check whether $T_g$ is surjective because an isometry is already injective. At this point I cannot continue and get stuck. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easiest to split your space $c = c_0 \oplus \mathbb{F}$, where $c_0$ are the sequences converging to $0$ and the $\mathbb{F}$ component corresponds to the limit. The first term $g(1) \lim f(k)$ in $T_g$ obviously corresponds to $\mathbb{F}^*$, and so you only have to show that all continuous linear functionals in $c_0^*$ can be represented by $\ell^1$ sequences.

If $f_N$ is the truncation of $f \in c_0$ at the index $N$, then $f_N \to f$ in the supremum norm. Now if $T \in c_0^*$, and if you define $g(k+1) = T(1_k)$, where $1_k$ is the sequence with a $1$ in position $k$ and zeros otherwise, then $T(f_N) = \sum_{k=1}^N g(k+1) f(k)$ for all $N$ and for all $f \in c_0$. Passing to the limit gives $T(f) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty g(k+1) f(k)$ for all $f \in c_0$.

Comment: I didn't quite get why we can pass to $c_0^*$. It seems that the $g$ defined in the second paragraph does not work for those $f\in c\setminus c_0$. Is it possible to do this question without splitting $c$?

Comment: Yes, you can do it without explicitly splitting, just write a sequence $f \in c_0$ as $f = \hat{f}+f_\infty$, where $f_\infty = \lim_{k\to\infty} f(k)$ and $\hat{f} \in c_0$. Define $g(k+1)$ as above, and $g(1) = T(1_\infty)$, where $1_\infty$ is the constant sequence with entries $1$. Then it is straightforward to check that it works. (Basically this is "splitting by hand", not a different construction.)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you very much