# Related to the dual space of $c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

In the analysis class, the instructor defined the following map between $\ell^1$ and $c^*$:

$$T:\ell^1\to c^*,\quad g\mapsto\phi_g$$

where $\phi_g$ is defined as

$$\phi_g:c\to\mathbb{C},\quad \phi_g(f)=g(1)\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n+1)f(n)$$

By showing that $T$ is an isometric isomorphism, we can conclude that $c^*=\ell^1$.

The proof of isometry can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051847/determine-whether-this-map-is-an-isomorphism) in the body of question. However, I am not quite sure about the onto part. My instructor proved the same way as in the answer of the linked question: for each $\phi\in c^*$, define
$$g(n)=\begin{cases}\phi(\mathbf{1}),&n=1\\
\phi(e_{n-1}),&n>1\end{cases}$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ is the sequence with all terms equal to 1, and $e_n$'s are the canonical coordinates. We can show that $g\in\ell^1$. Then my instructor said it is obvious that $\phi=\phi_g$. However, this does not seem quite convincing to me. I did the following: we have

$$\phi(f)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\phi(e_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)g(n+1).$$

which is missing a term $g(1)\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$.

Where are my mistakes and what is the right way to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is that you wrote

$$\phi(f) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\phi(e_n).$$

That would hold if we had

$$f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\cdot e_n\tag{$\ast$}$$

in the space $c$, but the series on the right hand side of $(\ast)$ converges only if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n) = 0$. For we have

$$\left\lVert f - \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)\cdot e_n\right\rVert = \sup_{n > N} \lvert f(n)\rvert \geqslant \left\lvert \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)\right\rvert.$$

The system $\{ e_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\}$ is a Schauder basis of the closed subspace $c_0$ of null-sequences, not of $c$.

The correct representation of $f\in c$ is

$$f = \lambda\cdot \mathbf{1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigl(f(n)-\lambda\bigr) \cdot e_n,\tag{1}$$

where $\lambda = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n)$.

Using the representation $(1)$, we obtain

$$\phi(f) = \lambda\phi(\mathbf{1}) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigl(f(n)-\lambda\bigr)\phi(e_n) = \lambda\cdot \left(g(1) - \sum_{n=2}^\infty g(n)\right) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\cdot g(n+1),$$

which however in general is different from $\phi_g$. One must choose a slightly different $g$ to get $\phi_g = \phi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this make sense. But there is one more question, can we find such a $g$ with $\phi=\phi_g$; and is $T$ indeed an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, we can find such a sequence. Let's call it $h$, since we've already used $g$. We want $\phi = \phi_h$, so we need $$h(1)\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) h(n+1) = \biggl(g(1) - \sum_{n=2}^\infty g(n)\biggr)\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)g(n+1)$$ for all $f\in c$. Taking $f = e_k$, we see that $h(k+1) = g(k+1) = \phi(e_k)$ for all $k$, so the only difference is in the first coordinate. Instead of $g(1) = \phi(\mathbf{1})$, we need $h(1) = \phi(\mathbf{1}) - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \phi(e_k)$.